# Is there any data race between std::weak_ptr and corresponding std::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

According to cppref, accessing `const` members of `shared_ptr` across multiple threads is safe. But is this statement valid when we have a `weak_ptr` that corresponds to a `shared_ptr`?

As an example assume the following code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

std::shared_ptr<int> sp;
std::weak_ptr<int> gw;

int main()
{
    sp = std::make_shared<int>(42);
    gw = sp;
    auto th1 = std::thread([]{
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            if (sp.use_count() > 1) {
                std::cout << i << "\n";
                std::this_thread::yield();
            }
        }
    });
    auto th2 = std::thread([]{
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            if (auto l = gw.lock()) {
                std::cout << "locked ->" << l.use_count() << "\n";
                std::this_thread::yield();
            }
        }
    });
    th1.join();
    th2.join();
}
```

This code creates 2 threads. One checks `use_count()` of `shared_ptr()` which is a `const` method and the other one use `lock()` to lock `weak_ptr()` which also is a `const` method too. But in reality, when I call `lock` on `weak_ptr`, I practically increase reference count of `shared_ptr` which is not thread safe unless reference count is internally guarded. I wonder if I will have a data race in situations like this. Is this supposed to be thread-safe by standard?

Comment: Like you said, you're only calling const functions so it has to be safe.  If a const function alters some internal state, it's on the implementation to get that right.

Comment: @NathanOliver the problem is that from what I got from cpp ref(if I assume it mirrors meaning of standard), standard does not define any operation relation between `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr`. So being `const` probably means **only on this object** and does not define anything for other related objects. `lock()` creates a new `shared_ptr` and I don't think it will be thread-safe.

Comment: In order for `weak_ptr` to work it has to share the control block with the `shared_ptr` you get it from.  That shared state is protected though since you call only `const` member functions on both pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The reference counter is atomic, so there are no data races in your example.

That being said, mutable operations on objects pointed by `std::shared_ptr` are not atomic, so they must be guarded as you would guard access via a plain pointer.

Comment: Just to note that the use of `use_count()` though being _thread-safe_ avoiding any _data race_ there is still a _race condition_ between the threads resulting with non deterministic behavior, which might be logically ok or not.